# In Excel how to do a pairing of A,B,C in form of AA,AB,AC,BA,BB,BC,CA,CB,CC depending upon the Consecutive row values in particular column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a help to do below thing.
Suppose I have column A which contains values either of A,B or C as Follows.

```
Column A
A
A
B
A
B
B
C
A
```

Now what I have to do is, I want to count pair of AA, AB, AC likewise, based on the two consecutive values, if First row contains A and 2nd row contains A, then AA count should be 1 likewise go on.
What I tired is I can get count for two cells only using following formula
`=COUNTIFS(A1, "=A",A2,"=B")`
But I don't how to go on increasing the rows.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You may use `SUMPRODUCT`.

List all possible combinations (e.g., in column C below).
Then in D1 use `=SUMPRODUCT((($A$1:$A$8&$A$2:$A$9)=C1)*1)`. Copy downwards.

Or list all possible combinations using two columns (e.g., in columns F,G below).
Then in H1 use `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$8=F1)*($A$2:$A$9=G1))`. Copy downwards.

Or you may use `COUNTIFS` as you meant to do.

Using two columns, in I1 use `=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$8,F1,$A$2:$A$9,G1)`. Copy downwards.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please look at the picture as I done the above in excel, may someone have more accurate answer.

[image]

Comment: Hello PaNazer,Thank you so much for answer, it's helping me somehow but what i want is if we are starting with row A2 and combining with A3 then it makes pair AA, next time skip A3 and start pait with A4 which is B and A5 is A which makes pair BA, is there any way to this, can we skip row in COUNTIFS formula?

Comment: You can use a simple trick here... First put the formula in B2 cell

Comment: then select both B1 and B2 cells copy and paste down to get the results as you described...

Comment: @KanchanKhandekar - Please remember to upvote/accept the answer if it worked for you.