# Count all people that signed up in "specific month" but converted "in other month"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What I have.

Sign-up Date of Users
Conversion Date of Users

What I would like is to count (for example) all users that signed up in "March 2019" and but "but converted in "April 2019".

I have problems already problems with putting in the data range.

I made a sepearte forumlar to calculate just the "Signups from March". It did not work with a countifs however it worked with using a countif - countif ... see below.

That was the forumlar that worked for counting the "Signups for Month".

```
C18 = 1/3/2019
C19 = 1/4/2019
Sheet 1: is my data sheet
I:I = Signup Date
M:M = Converson Date


=(countif('Sheet1!I:I,">="&C18)-Countif('Sheet1'!I:I,">"&C19))
```

now i just need to ad the conversion date somehow.

Any clue?

Comment: This question looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40572978/in-excel-how-to-do-a-pairing-of-a-b-c-in-form-of-aa-ab-ac-ba-bb-bc-ca-cb-cc-depe/57489002#57489002

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(C18)=MONTH(signConvTBL[Signup]))*(YEAR(C18)=YEAR(signConvTBL[Signup]))*(MONTH(C19)=MONTH(signConvTBL[Conversion]))*(YEAR(C19)=YEAR(signConvTBL[Conversion])))
```

Note that I used a Table and structured references for your signup/conversion date table since using whole column references would result in long calculation times.

Answer (score 0):

Presume you have given a **name** to `Column I` as **Signup_Date**, and given a **name** to `Column M` as **Conversion_Date**.

You can use the following formula to find the desired count. Please note it is an array formula so you need to press **`Ctrl+Shift+Enter`** to make it work.

```
{=SUM(--(--MONTH(Signup_Date)&YEAR(Signup_Date)&MONTH(Conversion_Date)&YEAR(Conversion_Date)="3201942019"))}
```

**MONTH** function will return **3** for any dates in March, and return **4** for any dates in April;

**YEAR** function will return **2019** for any dates within the year of 2019;

So the logic of my solution is to ask, if I concatenate (using **&**) the dates in Column I with the dates in Column M, will it return **3201942019**? Which can be read as 3 (March) & 2019 & 4 (April) & 2019.

If so, return **TRUE**. Then you can convert TURE to numerical value **1** by using **`--`** which works the same as **NUMBERVALUE** function.

The last step is to use **SUM** to add up all **TRUE** (or 1) in the array.

See below screen-shot for more clarifications. Please note the User column H is unnecessary just for demonstration only. It is not used in any part of the formula.

[image: Solution]

One more thing, I hard-coded the look up criteria to **3201942019** in my formula. You can **give a name** to this criteria and store it somewhere in your worksheet, and change it to some other dates such as 5201862019 which will then count the number of users who sign up in May 2018 and converted in June 2019. Or you can use a formula to dynamically update this look up criteria if needed.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is similar to [In Excel how to do a pairing of A,B,C in form of AA,AB,AC,BA,BB,BC,CA,CB,CC depending upon the Consecutive row values in particular column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40572978/in-excel-how-to-do-a-pairing-of-a-b-c-in-form-of-aa-ab-ac-ba-bb-bc-ca-cb-cc-depe)
I will base the answer on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57489002/2707864).
My system is in Spanish, so the date format is DD/MM/YYYY.

With reference to the figure below, where

```
Col A: User ID
Col B: Sign-up Date of User
Col C: Conversion Date of User
Cols D-G: Helper columns with month/year of sign-up/conversion.
Col I: Target sign-up month
Col J: Target conversion month
```

I post two methods to get the intended results.

Using `SUMPRODUCT`.
K1 contains `=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($B$1:$B$9)=MONTH(I1))*(YEAR($B$1:$B$9)=YEAR(I1))*(MONTH($C$1:$C$9)=MONTH(J1))*(YEAR($C$1:$C$9)=YEAR(J1)))`.
Copy downwards.

Using `COUNTIFS` (much less versatile).
This needs the 4 helper columns.
I1 contains `=COUNTIFS($D$1:$D$9,MONTH(I1),$E$1:$E$9,YEAR(I1),$F$1:$F$9,MONTH(J1),$G$1:$G$9,YEAR(J1))`.
Copy downwards.

References may be replaced by other ranges, including whole columns as you mention in the OP.

[image]